# Why I get multiple UILocalNotifications in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

This is my function:

```
func sendNotificationEvery() {
    print("HEY!")
    notification.alertBody = "Message here" // text that will be displayed in the notification
    notification.fireDate = NSDate()  // right now (when notification will be fired)
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound

    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute // this line defines the interval at which the notification will be repeated
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

and I call it here:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    sendNotificationEvery()
}
```

So, the issue is: When I close my app it send 3-4 notifications instead of 1. How can I  fix this issue? And I want to know, why it happens?

Comment: Are you ever unscheduling old notifications?

Comment: Use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications` to cancel old notifications.

Comment: Why have u set the repeat interval to every minute?

Comment: @Muneeba I'm just testing. Later it will 1 or 3 hours

Comment: @Sulthan will it repeat notifications in this case?

Comment: @Wain will it repeat notifications in this case? Look, I set timer to 1 minute. But when I close my app it immediately gets a notification and in 203 second get the second, and third in few seconds again =/

Comment: yes, you set it to repeat and you keep adding new one...

Comment: @Wain how can I solve this problem? =/

Comment: I don't really get why you're using local notifications at all. The above comment from @Sulthan already tells you how to solve it.

Comment: @Wain I just do not need in Push Notifications. I need show them in time

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I imagine your requirement as "while closing the app you have to show the notification".

As per this, instead of writing the above code in **viewWillDisappear**, write in Appdelegate class, **- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application** method.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: It still sends me 3-4 notifications

Comment: For testing, just uninstall the app and change the device time to future date. And test the app now. Remove the code from viewWillDisappear method.

Comment: Increase the notification.repeatInterval and check.